# Exponential Radioactive Decay Problem

Tags: calculus

A radioactive substance is known to decay at a rate proportional to the amount
present. If half of a given sample has disappeared after 1200 years, find ( to the
nearest percent) what percentage remains after 1800 years.

Answer (score 1):

The decay is exponential. So at time $t$ years the proportion remaining is
$e^{-\lambda t}$ where $\lambda$ is a constant. You have
$e^{-1200\lambda}=1/2$ and want to find $e^{-1800\lambda}$. But
$$e^{-1800\lambda}=(e^{-1200\lambda})^{3/2}=(0.5)^{3/2}.$$
Time to pull out your calculator!

Answer (score 0):

So, as you can see, the exponential function that describes the percentage left is $100(0.5)^\frac{t}{1200}$.

Therefore, after 1800 years, there is $100(0.5)^{1.5}$ % left, or 35.355%.

Also, the differential equation that describes this change is dP/dt = kP.

dP/P = k dt, so ln|P| = kt+C, and P = Ce^(kt). Since our starting value is 100%, or undecayed, C=100.

And by plugging in P=0.5 when t=1200, we deduce that k=ln(0.5)/1200. Therefore, the same solution can be rewritten as 100e^(tln(0.5)/1200). We plug in t=1800 for the needed value.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be the amount. The model is $dn/dt = -rn$ or $n = n_0e^{-rt}$. We have $n/n_0 = 1/2 =e^{-r\times 1200}$, thus $r = (\ln 2)/1200$. What is $e^{-r\times 1800}$?